# How to migrate wordpress users from one blog to another

Tags: users, multisite, backup

I have a client that has a single install outside of her network installation. I need to migrate the users with their passwords into the network installation. I've tried backupbuddy  but it seems to skip the users. Any idea how I could pull this off manually?

Answer (score 1):

Normally BackupBuddy should transfer users just fine, it might be issue with importing into multisite installation. Have you tried asking developers about it?

As for more hands-on approach I'd try creating users in network and then overwrite hashes of their passwords in database with values from original installation.

Comment: Oh that's a terrific idea, I'll try that tonight. And no I haven't asked the devs yet. Their support structure is tedious.