# how to migrate wpmu from one host to the other?

Tags: multisite, database, migration, installation, backup

this issus is different fromm [How to migrate wordpress users from one blog to another](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30820/how-to-migrate-wordpress-users-from-one-blog-to-another)

since i am using WPMU, i have backup the database, and then import it to the other host, also i have changed the wp-config.php, but the web page just shows that i cannot connect to database, what's wrong?

the error page is as follows:

Error establishing database connection

Answer (score 0):

> Error establishing database connection

Can Only mean one thing and that is an Error establishing database connection,
check your wp-config.php again and see that the database settings is correct and also make sure that your database user as permission on the database server.

Comment: it is allowed to access my database from everywhere, that is %, and the user/password in wp-config.php is correct, so i am confused why failed to establish database connection